# react-chartjs-2 not able to customize x axis labels

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I am trying to customize the `x` Axis labels using `react-chartjs-2`.

I can use the `callback` function in the `ticks` option in the chart `options` but the `value` and `values` that I get as parameters in the `callback` function is not necessary as they are just values. (I am using horizontal bar chart by using `y` axis as an index axis)

And those labels depend on the state of the `React` component that I fetch via `react-query`.
So, I am wondering if it's a good way to include that `options` variable as a **memoized** one inside the component.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you figure it out?